# Обработка прокрутки

Tags: android

Можно ли обработать событие прокрутки ScrollView?

Answer (score 1):

Можно. Разрешаем. (детали - [onScrollChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html)).

Comment: @KoVadim, по ссылке ж ведь только событие, кое вызывется при скролле... А вот листенер ставить на него, согласно гуглу, тот ещё хардкор, ибо его по дефолту нэма(